# Access complex Json file with Nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular6

I am facing a problem while fetching the particular array;

[my json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKeHV.jpg)

- ATM/Cash ( each id from array(11) )

  ```
         -id:2998390918
         -id:2998390990
           .
           .
           .
         -id:2999363236
  ```
- Account Transfer ( each id from array(30) )

  ```
         -id:2998390928
         -id:2998390929
           .
           .
           .
         -id:2998390979
  ```

  .
    .
    .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over object and print

```js
var o = {
    "Healthcare/Medical":
    Array(167),

        "Personal Care":
    Array(88),

        Miscellaneous_Services:Array(340),

        General_Merchandise:Array(110),

        Home_Improvement:Array(292)
};

Object.keys(o).forEach((k)=>{
    console.log(k);
    o[k].forEach((e)=>{
        console.log(`-id[${e.id}]`);
    });
});
```

Comment: This code brings me very close to the output. I want actual value of id

Comment: this is very helpful for me.Thank you So much @Shishir Arora